# How I Can do xml to json conversion using xsl in C# or using azure logic apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to convert Xml to Json using XSLT file but the Jsonx that i got back after conversion , tried converting the same into Json but it is not in format of Json i need, used below code for conversion:

```
       XPathDocument mydata = new XPathDocument(xmlPath);
        //Create a new XslTransform object.
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

        //Load the stylesheet.
        xslt.Load(xslPath);

        XmlDocument resultDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocumentFragment resultFrag = resultDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();

        using (XmlWriter xw = resultFrag.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            xslt.Transform(mydata, null, xw);
            xw.Close();
        }

       JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(resultFrag);
```

After Json conversion getting result as follows , below code is just small snip of json:

```
"json:string": [{
            "@name": "@class",
            "#text": "Jack"
        }, {
            "@name": "Version",
            "#text": "2.0"
        }]
```

Required Json is as below:

```
"json:string": [{
            "@class": "Jack"
        }, 
        {
            "Version": "2.0"
        }]
```